# How can I clone only a bootable windows partition(not the disk) to a file?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, clone, gpt

I have a hard disk which is `1 Tb` in size. I have created and installed `windows Xp` on a partition of size `10 Gb`. I want to clone the partition to a file on another disk such that I can `dd` the file to any new disk resulting it to be a exact same clone of `10 Gb` partition.

**NOTE** I do not want to clone the entire `1Tb` disk into a file but just the bootable `10Gb` partition. The partition is a `GPT` type.

I am specifically looking for any commands that I can use from booting the system through a `live CD`.

Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: If you can give up dd usage you can try Clonezilla - its will be faster than dd (only used blocks are cloned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to do what I wanted.

I used `gnu parted` and `dd` to copy only the bootable partition.

I first used `parted` command to `print`the start and end of the drive say `/dev/sda` and then noted the start and end of the bootable drive.
For e.g end is at 7890Mb just convert this into bytes and divide by 512 which is the block size of the drive I was working in. Lets say this result is `N`. The result would be the count you will supply to `dd` command.

Now just use `dd if=/dev/driveWhereBootablePartionExist of=/backup/img.img` count=N from above bs=512(or block size)

This resulted in fully bootable image file for the partition equal to partition size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dd` to copy the entire partition, as in:

```
dd if=/dev/sda3 of=windows-xp.img
```

(Change `/dev/sda3` and the output filename as necessary.) You'd then reverse the process to copy it back:

```
dd if=windows-xp.img of=/dev/sda3 bs=4096
```

Note that I've added `bs=4096` as an option. This causes output to be sent in chunks of 4096 bytes, which is likely to be faster on most modern disks. (This will have little or no effect when creating the backup, though.)

Although using `dd`, as you specified in your question, will work, it's inefficient. A better way is to use a tool called `ntfsclone`, at least assuming the partition uses NTFS. (This is a Linux tool. Based on the fact that you specified `dd` and said you're using a live CD, I'm assuming it's Linux.) To clone a partition with `ntfsclone`, you'd use something like this:

```
ntfsclone --save-image --output windows-xp.img /dev/sda3
```

Restoring it requires a command like this:

```
ntfsclone --restore-image --overwrite /dev/sda3 windows-xp.img
```

There are more examples of its use near the end of the `ntfsclone` man page (type `man ntfsclone` to read it).

The advantage of `ntfsclone` is that it uses a sparse file format, which means that it doesn't back up sectors that aren't in use. By contrast, `dd` copies everything, so if the partition has lots of unused space, `dd` will probably take longer and will definitely chew up more disk space. Depending on the state of the disk before you installed XP, compressing the `dd` backup might not help that much, since the unused sectors might have old data on them.

Either way, there are a few caveats to keep in mind:

- Both `ntfsclone` and `dd` will back up the boot loader data in the Windows partition, but not the boot loader on the disk's MBR. You'll have to back that up separately. (OTOH, you said that the disk is GPT, and Windows XP can't boot from GPT disks, except for some exotic Itanium builds, IIRC. Are you using this in a virtualization environment?)
- Both `dd` and `ntfsclone` pose a risk of serious damage if you enter the wrong device filename, particularly when restoring the image. If the restore target is the wrong partition, you're likely to wipe out everything on that target, which could be disastrous. Be *very* careful!
- You need `root` privileges to execute these commands. Depending on your live CD environment, that might be the default, or you might have to add `sudo` to the start of each command.

Answer (score 0):

Try [gparted](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/). It can copy partitions to another disk.
Or dd can be used like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M
```

You need to reinstall boot loader to make it bootable after such copy.

Comment: I do not want to touch the bootloader part separately. Thus I asked this question. Thanks for the response though.